# Imgur upload error

Tags: php, image, laravel, imgur

I am using Imgur to upload photos from my site.

This is my code

```
$client_id = '*********';

$image = file_get_contents($_FILES['update_profile_photo']['tmp_name']);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Client-ID $client_id"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('image' => base64_encode($image)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$reply = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$reply = json_decode($reply);

echo "<h3>Image</h3>";
printf('<img height="180" src="%s" >', $reply->data->link);

echo "<h3>API Debug</h3><pre>";
var_dump($reply);
```

When I first upload a file it printed out the image. But from the next try I am unable to view the file and in laravel I get an error like this

[image]

when clear `printf('<img height="180" src="%s" >', $reply->data->link);` to check the result of `var_dump()`, it gives me like this

```
object(stdClass)#219 (3) {
  ["data"]=>
  object(stdClass)#215 (3) {
    ["error"]=>
    object(stdClass)#212 (4) {
      ["code"]=>
      int(1016)
      ["message"]=>
      string(27) "Banned country attempt (IN)"
      ["type"]=>
      string(16) "Exception_Logged"
      ["exception"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    ["request"]=>
    string(13) "/3/image.json"
    ["method"]=>
    string(4) "POST"
  }
  ["success"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["status"]=>
  int(400)
}
```

I am living in India (It is telling in message that Banned Country attempt)
I want to know how to fix this error? Why first time it worked and now it dont.

I am in localhost, didnt host yet. 

Is this problem of my code?

**Please tell me how to fix this**

Comment: `Banned country attempt (IN)`

Comment: @PedroLobito So you mean Imgur is banned for India? I should use some other site instead of Imgur or is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Sry, but I've no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imgur is blocked in India, so you are unable to access the API.

The only reliable way to fix this, is to access the API through a proxy.

Source: http://thehackernews.com/2015/01/indian-government-blocks-32-sites.html

Comment: Thanks for the information. Can you suggest me some other sites which I can use for uploading images through api?